# Как правильно: в галактике созвездия или в галактике в созвездии?

Tags: окончания

Они находились в галактике Подсолнух созвездия Гончих Псов или в галактике Подсолнух в созвездии Гончих Псов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно: *Они находились в галактике Подсолнух **созвездия Гончие Псы.***

Здесь используется **родительный падеж с определительным значением.**

Если использовать два предложных падежа, то нужно будет обозначать уточняющие отношения, то есть ставить запятую.

https://v-kosmose.com/katalog-nebesnyih-obektov-sharlya-messe/galaktika-podsolnuh/

Красивая спиральная галактика Подсолнух (М 63, NGC 5055) созвездия Гончие Псы.